# Regex to find last consonant followed by a vowel in a word

Tags: regex, vb.net

I would like to match the last consonant followed by a vowel in a word. Right now I am using:

```
([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiou])+
```

This matches every case, instead of just the end of words. For example: `Welcome` matches `co` and `me`, but should ***only*** match `me`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find last consonant followed by a vowel in a word, Use this pattern

```
((?![aeiou])[a-zA-Z][aeiou])(?!\S*((?![aeiou])[a-z][aeiou]))
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/61)

Comment: @Greg: Edited my answer to include `A-Z`

Answer (score 2):

Just put a word boundary modifier (`\b`) on the end:

```
([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiou]\b)+
```

Also, unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do, the one-or-more group match is unnecessary.  The following is sufficient:

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiou]\b
```

As @fejese points out below, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to match the last consonant in a word that's followed by a vowel, but only one per word, that allows for the following possibilities.

- Word ends in (consonant)(vowel)
- Word contains (consonant)(vowel) and ends in additional vowel(s)
- Word contains (consonant)(vowel) and ends in consonant(s) *not followed by vowels*

In that case, you can do the following:

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz][aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*\b
```

Comment: This only works if the last consonant followed by a vowel is also the last two character. Not sure if that's what OP intended to do

Comment: @fejese You're correct. I need it to find the last occurrence regardless where it appears in the word (not just at the end). With the above code from Ethan mistakes isn't caught when it should find 'ke'

Comment: ((?![aeiou])[a-z][aeiou])(?![a-z]*[aeiou]) seems to work where your last edit @EthanBrown misses 'family' for example.

Comment: It misses "family" because "y" isn't a vowel in the OPs example.  I'm not going to get into a debate about whether or not "y" is a vowel or consonant (it is sometimes one, sometimes the other).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative look ahead to forbid the pattern to be repeated again:

```
/([^aeiou][aeiou])(?!.*[^aeiou][aeiou])/
```

Please note that I don't know if VB.net supports (variable length) negative look-aheads or not.